# Ajax sometimes works, sometimes doesn't in Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I am trying to fetch data from my database using AJAX. My Laravel Controller returning string in JSON response. But my AJAX sometimes works, sometimes doesn't.I get "internal server error" when Ajax don't work i mean when the data is not loaded. But the problem doesn't happen in safari browser. Here is my AJAX code.

```
 $(function(){
     var checking_html = '<img src="img/loader.gif" />';

     $("#bond").change(function () {
         $('#load').html(checking_html);
         var x = $('#bond').val();

         $.ajax({
             type: 'POST',
             url: "{{ URL::route('bond.list') }}",
             data: {
                 '_token': $('input[name=_token]').val(),
                 'x': x
             },
             success: function(response) {
                 if(response[0]['bond_num'] == 400000){
                     response[0]['bond_num']='Premium';
                 }
                 html_output = '';
                 for(i=0; i<response.length; i++){
                     html_output += '<option value="'+response[i]['publish_date']+'">'+response[i]['publish_date']+' , '+response[0]['bond_num']+' Bond</option>';
                     if(i==0){
                         html_output += '<option value="all">ALL</option>';
                     }
                 }
                 $('#choice').empty().append(html_output);
                 $('#load').html('');
             },
             error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                 alert('Error get data from ajax');
             }
         });
     });
 });
```

Comment: What exactly happens?Does it give you error....?

Comment: *It doesn't work*. Okay cool. What doesn't? My car sometimes doesn't work either, do you know what's the problem?

Comment: @Loek my magic orb told me you should check your ignition. No really TO, you should state the exact error or problem so we can have a proper look.

Comment: The whole process is when i will click on a dropdown select option then this ajax call will happen and we will get data loaded in a div...Sometimes the data comes sometimes don't...

Comment: you are probably not going inside  success: function(response) , when your function doesn't work. The problem must be either url or data in AJAX, Since it works sometimes so url must be fine, problem must be the data..'_token' and 'x', this datas might be receiving blank or something weird which in turn might be giving you no response... This is what I could say in the broader sense... if you'll be more specific with the outputs and errors then you can get better help.

Comment: I get internal server error when data not loaded...I mean when ajax don't work.

Comment: So it means problem is from your side, try clearing your cache. refresh using ctrl+f5

Comment: But the problem doesn't happen in safari browser

Comment: The problem was the token. I removed the token part from my AJAX call and disabled token verification for the route. Now working perfectly every time.

Comment: Yes,  Since it works sometimes so url must be fine, problem must be the data..'_token' and 'x', and if you still want to use token then check the syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the token. I removed the token part from my AJAX call and disabled token verification for the route. Now working perfectly every time.

Answer (score 0):

You need to JSON.parse() your result:

```
 $.ajax({
     type: 'GET',
     url: "{{ URL::route('bond.list') }}",
     data: {
         '_token': $('input[name=_token]').val(),
         'x': x
     },
     success: function(response) {
         var response = JSON.parse(response);
         console.log(response);
     }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

so on success function `console.log(response)` and on console please check the result if coming and also open the network section on browser  and see the time take by the ajax request after doing this you will get the idea where the problem is. Thank you

Comment: I get "internal server error" when Ajax don't work i mean when data not loaded.

Comment: But the problem doesn't happen in safari browser

Comment: Are you clicking very fast again and again or please check if the application got log out this is what i see the issue and token changes please check

Comment: Yes.Thank u sir. The problem was the token. I removed the token part from my AJAX call and disabled token verification for the route. Now working perfectly every time.